# What is the difference in saving?

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.4

I know that I can save my objects in two different ways.
But what is the diference between these lines?

```
Ebean.save(network);
network.save();
```

Comment: Can you show some information on the `network` object? Show the class declaration so we can see the type and who it extends, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

The Play framework provides the `save()` method, and others, by default on all `model` types that are mapped as persisted entities.

The method does the same thing as `Ebean.save()` but gives the benefit of abstracting away the details of the vendor specific ORM being used. If you are using Play framework, it is a best practice to call the `save()` method directly on your model/entity than to call methods on `EBean` directly.

Comment: Although this is generally correct I'd like to point out that in recent versions of Play and Ebean - Ebean now provides the Model object and hence the save() method. That is, in recent versions Ebean is providing both these save() methods and it isn't anything to do with Play anymore.